# Action menus drop down not displayed when using Lightning Datatable

Tags: lightning-datatable

The action menu in my `<lightning:datatable` is not appearing.

**Component**

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" controller="LightningDataTableController">
    <aura:attribute name="mydata" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="mycolumns" type="List"/>

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />

    <lightning:datatable data="{! v.mydata }" class="action-test" 
        columns="{! v.mycolumns }" 
        keyField="Id" hideCheckboxColumn="true" onrowaction="{! c.handleRowAction }"/> 

</aura:component
```

**JsController**

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {                       
        helper.getDataHelper(component, event);
    },
    handleRowAction: function (cmp, event, helper) {
        var action = event.getParam('action');
        var row = event.getParam('row');

        switch (action.name) {
            case 'show_details':
                alert('Showing Details: ' + JSON.stringify(row));
                break;
            case 'delete':
                helper.removeBook(cmp, row)
                break;
        }
    }
})
```

**Helper Js**

```
({
    getDataHelper : function(component, event) {
        var action = component.get("c.getAccRecords");
        //Set the Object parameters and Field Set name
        action.setParams({
            strObjectName : 'Account',
            strFieldSetName : 'DataTableFieldSet'
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if(state === 'SUCCESS'){
                component.set("v.mycolumns", response.getReturnValue().lstDataTableColumns);
                component.set("v.mydata", response.getReturnValue().lstDataTableData);    
            }else if (state === 'ERROR'){
                var errors = response.getError();
                if (errors) {
                    if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                        console.log("Error message: " +
                                    errors[0].message);
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log("Unknown error");
                }
            }else{
                console.log('Something went wrong, Please check with your admin');
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);   
    }
})
```

**Controller Class**

```
public class LightningDataTableController {
    /*
    Method Name : getAccRecords
    Purpose     : To get the wrapper of Columns and Headers
    */
    @AuraEnabled
    public static DataTableResponse getAccRecords(String strObjectName, String strFieldSetName){                
        DataTableResponse response ;
        try
        {
        //Get the fields from FieldSet
        Schema.SObjectType SObjectTypeObj = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(strObjectName);
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult DescribeSObjectResultObj = SObjectTypeObj.getDescribe();            
        Schema.FieldSet fieldSetObj = DescribeSObjectResultObj.FieldSets.getMap().get(strFieldSetName);

        //To hold the table hearders 
        List<DataTableColumns> lstDataColumns = new List<DataTableColumns>();

        //Field to be queried - fetched from fieldset
        List<String> lstFieldsToQuery = new List<String>();

        //The final wrapper response to return to component
         response = new DataTableResponse();

        for( Schema.FieldSetMember eachFieldSetMember : fieldSetObj.getFields() ){
            String dataType = String.valueOf(eachFieldSetMember.getType()).toLowerCase();
            //This way we can set the type of a column
            //We do not get the exact type from schema object which matches to lightning:datatable component structure
            if(dataType == 'datetime'){
                dataType = 'date';
            }
            //Create a wrapper instance and store label, fieldname and type.
            DataTableColumns datacolumns = new DataTableColumns( String.valueOf(eachFieldSetMember.getLabel()) , 
                                                                String.valueOf(eachFieldSetMember.getFieldPath()), 
                                                                String.valueOf(eachFieldSetMember.getType()).toLowerCase() );
            lstDataColumns.add(datacolumns);
            lstFieldsToQuery.add(String.valueOf(eachFieldSetMember.getFieldPath()));
        }

        //Form an SOQL to fetch the data - Set the wrapper instance and return as response
        if(! lstDataColumns.isEmpty()){            
            response.lstDataTableColumns = lstDataColumns;
            String query = 'SELECT ' + String.join(lstFieldsToQuery, ',') + ' FROM Account';
            System.debug(query);
            response.lstDataTableData = Database.query(query);
        }

        System.debug('----------- Response : '+response);
        return response;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.debug('--**--------- Response : '+response);
            System.debug('--------- response error : '+e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

    }

    //Wrapper class to hold Columns with headers
    public class DataTableColumns {
        @AuraEnabled
        public String label {get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled       
        public String fieldName {get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public String type {get;set;}

        //Create and set three variables label, fieldname and type as required by the lightning:datatable
        public DataTableColumns(String label, String fieldName, String type){
            this.label = label;
            this.fieldName = fieldName;
            this.type = type;            
        }
    }

    //Wrapper calss to hold response - This response is used in the lightning:datatable component
    public class DataTableResponse {
        @AuraEnabled
        public List<DataTableColumns> lstDataTableColumns {get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public List<sObject> lstDataTableData {get;set;}                

        public DataTableResponse(){
            lstDataTableColumns = new List<DataTableColumns>();
            lstDataTableData = new List<sObject>();
        }
    }
}
```

**This is how my Page looks right now**

[image]

The last column containing drop down menus for delete/edit action for the row is not visible unlike how it is shown in documentation
[image]

FYI Right now I am viewing the component in aura application only for testing it first
Is there is something I am missing?

Comment: Where are you setting the value of `v.mycolumns ` ?

Comment: I have added Js and controller code. Please check it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Robs mentions in his comment, you need to setup the actions in the columns data e.g.:

```
    var columns = [];

    // Data column definitions added here

    // Add the actions column
    var actions = [
        {label: 'Edit', name: 'EDIT'},
        {label: 'Delete', name: 'DELETE'}
    ];
    columns.push({type: 'action', typeAttributes: { rowActions: actions } });

    component.set("v.mycolumns", columns);
```

It looks like you may have not added the action column in your code.

Comment: @MonalisaDas No problem. There are quite a lot of parts to get setup in these tables.