# Is it possible to change the sequence of row action menus of lightning data table from last to first

Tags: lightning-datatable

I just have a requirement where I need to show the edit/delete action menus of row to the first column of lightning:datatable rather than last. I wonder will it be possible since it is pertaining to its standard look of this component

[image]

Thanks

Comment: My assumption is that you could place the actions in any column (see my answer to [Action menus drop down not displayed when using Lightning Datatable](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/222547/action-menus-drop-down-not-displayed-when-using-lightning-datatable)). But that would leave your UI inconsistent with the platform convention (AFAIK) of making that the last column.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. If you check the official documentation:

### https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/documentation

action: has the attribute menuAlignment (defaults to right).
So, you just to set it to the left.